# difference between <Type>function and function name():Type in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
function getCounter(): Counter {
    let counter = <Counter>function (start: number) { };
    counter.interval = 123;
    return counter;
}
```

Look at line 2 in above code. Why can't I do `function (start: number): Counter`.

I guess what i am asking is diffrence between `<type>` and  `:type`

Comment: you should read about generics in typescript, and in general.

Comment: One is type assertion and the other is function return type. I can't see how they can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

`:type` - is a declaration of the function's return value type. For example:

```
let counter = function (start: number): number {}
let result = counter(1);
```

Here, the type of the `result` variable will be `number`.

See [function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) for more details.

`<type>` - is a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html), meaning that it tells the compiler that the value that comes after this assertion is of the specified type. In your case, the variable `counter` will have the type `Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) from the TypeScript handbook. The chapter Type assertions explains the `<Type>` syntax. The book is very useful to learn the basics of TypeScript.

So basically the `:Type` syntax is used to state which type a variable is. So for example:

```
let example: string = "This is a string";
let exampleNumber: number = 12;
```

But bear in mind that a lot of TypeScript types can be inferred. So this code will have the same result:

```
let example = "This is a string";
let exampleNumber = 12;
```

Sometimes TypeScript code gives you an `any` type. Which actually means that it can be anything. With both the  and :Type syntax you will be able to threat it like a strong typed variable. So the code will look like:

```
function test(arg: any): number {
    // Threat the arg variable as string;
    let example: string = arg;
    // Threat the arg variable as string by using Type assertion.
    let otherExample = <string> arg;

    // Returns arg but the return type = :number so the caller will have a number variable.
    return arg;
}
// Nr will be of type number by the compiler.
let nr = test(12);
```